# TTY ,SWIG and PHP

Tags: php, c++, swig, tty, archlinux

Need some help here. I have a c++ library for communicating with an embedded module (ArchLinux) via tty. This library was compiled/converted into php using swig.

The issue now is that a sample program written in php and run from the command line executes as expected but when this same code is used as part of a web page's functionality it fails to execute.

My assumption based on my limited linux knowledge is that tty requires a console in order to run which is why it fails to run as part of a webpage??

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can get this to work? I have read something about using posix_ttyname but I cant seem to find any code samples that demonstrate its use.

I have attached the offending c++ files along with a test main.php which works for review.

Thanks everyone

http://www.mediafire.com/?ctblcvsy86mdg8p

Comment: Do you get an error message when the code fails to execute? Check the Apache logs...

Comment: I don't see the files or a link...are you sure you added them

Comment: Apologies for the missing file. I have edited the question to attach them. Cheers for the help

Comment: I checked the access and error logs, there is no information there when the page is accessed. I assume that is because the c++ code /php generated by swig exits when it is unable to connect to the tty? Its just a guess though. Cheers for the help

Answer (score 0):

[`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) variable is available only when script is called from CLI. If you don't want to change the script so it could be called from web, you can try calling it from another script as

```
exec('main.php param');
```

Just like you do from command line.

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch, the main.php file was only an example that demonstrates what I am intending to do. `$argv` is just a string param so writing the sequence with a filled in argv fails to run even though the string param is the same. I cant use exec because I need a handle to the ZigbeeControl after its initialized. Cheers

Comment: You'll still have instance of ZigbeeControl inside of main.php no matter how it was called. If you want to make your script more web-oriented, pass arguments via `$_GET`.

Comment: Hi Hnatt, I have attached a sample project with the intended way of using it for comment [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?9rmdqqjk41b6agd). You can find this is zigbee/application/views/header_view.php. I cant add the so files as they are commercially sensitive. I am going to try running this on a standard distro to see if it makes a difference. Cheers

Comment: Just an update, by running it in a standard distro, loads of issues have been resolved. I have managed to track the issue down to the dl function that is generated by swig when converting to c++. I understand that the function is deprecated in php5 which is what I am using. the offending script is below `  if (strtolower(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'win') {
    if (!dl('php_zigbeedriver.dll')) return;
  } `

Comment: Another update after lots of graft, apparently the dl command works in cli mode only in php5.3 which is why it works in the console and not in the web page. I have installed suPhp and I am attempting to get it to work that way.